# problems adding Hunspellx86.dll reference (NHunspell) in visualStudio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

when i try adding reference HunSpellX86.dll to my application an error

" A reference to "E:\SEO\Hunspellx86.dll" could not be added. No types libraries were found in the component"

Can anyone help?

Comment: What are these files supposed to be? Where are you trying to download them from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on using [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) with managed (C#) code, you cannot reference directly the hunspell DLL which is unmanaged, and is not COM (does not have a Type Library). You need to copy Hunspellx86.dll manually into the execution directory alongside nhunspell.dll. Because it's unmanaged, it's not copied automatically

Please check [NHunspell - Hunspell for the .NET platform](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/hunspell-for-net.aspx)

Comment: i can add NHunspell.dll its just the  Hunspellx86.dll that is giving trouble.....
is there any way i can do that????

Comment: @kaaggi - in your question, you say you add a reference to hunspellx86. Please check your question if you want help.

Comment: @user111 - you should not add a reference to HunSpellX86.dll if you want managed code. you must reference a managed DLL, like NHunspell.dll, which will in turn use HunSpellX86.dll. Plus make sure your application is compiled for X86, not X64 nor "Any CPU".

Comment: i did referenced Nhunspell.dll only bu it will give me the error
"Hunspell Intel 32Bit DLL not found: C:\Users\ipsha\Desktop\synoymdemo\bin\Hunspellx86.dll"

Comment: @user111 - you just need to copy Hunspellx86.dll manually in the execution directory, aside nhunspell.dll. Because it's unmanaged, it's not copied automatically.